# Managing dependencies in a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 2 JARs that are supposed to be imported into a maven project. I followed this tutorial (click [here](http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/)) and imported those JARs into my maven project. Basically, I executed this code in the terminal:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myfile.jar -DgroupId=mygroup -DartifactId=com.mygroup.project -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=lib -DcreateChecksum=true`
and then I imported the library into my Maven project.

All this works fine. However, the JARs I am importing are supposed to have few dependencies themselves. As I understand, Maven handles the internal dependencies automatically. Now I have a list of dependencies (with group ID, artefact ID and version) but I don't understand where do I write those. In the folder 1.0 of the library, there is a file called myjar-1.0.pom. I tried writing the dependencies there but it was of no use.

Could you tell me a way of manually telling Maven to load up a few dependencies?

I also tried specifying these dependencies in the main *pom.xml* but it results in errors - saying the *repo-url/dependency/file.pom* was not found. So I guess it needs to be mentioned in internal dependency only - but I can't figure out a way of manually defining them. Will I need to create a pom.xml within those libraries, or is there something that I am missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

1. write the pom for you jar, and declare the dependencies in the pom.
2. user mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar -DpomFile=path-to-pom to install you jar.

link: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following JARs and dependencies:

```
myMavenProject
--> library1.jar
    --> library2.jar
    --> library3.jar
```

(I'm assuming that your `library1`, `library2` and `library3` are not Maven projects)

For each `library1`, `library2` and `library3`, perform `mvn install:install-file` like what you've did before:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=library1.jar -DgroupId=com.mygroup.project -DartifactId=library1 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

(Note that I swap your `groupId` and `artifactId` here)

Then in your Maven project, update your `pom.xml` to have following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>library1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>library2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>library3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Unless you have a very specific requirement, I'm not sure why you want to have `-DlocalRepositoryPath=lib` extra options for Maven and not using your local M2 Repository.

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing the same thing before, but it turns out there is HUGE number of dependencies for the JAR i wish to use. So will probably have to go for something else, like custom POM generation..
Thanks

Comment: since you have a HUGE number of dependencies, put those dependencies into one folder and run a Shell script that invoke Maven for each of them (I assume the groupId is the same, and you can use the filename for the artifactId).Not sure if this is a viable option for you ;). Unless you're having a lots of transitive dependencies in those dependent JARs!?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following might be working, but it is not [*The Maven Way!*](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/04/the-maven-way.html) If you will follow this path, you will have troubles all along the way!

You'd better read some tutorial from the [maven user center](https://maven.apache.org/users/index.html) or the [maven books and resources](https://maven.apache.org/articles.html) page. *Maven: the definitve guide* for example is available online for free.

Why the approach you are currently following is not good and how you'd do this better is mentioned by Stephen Connolly on a [very good blog post](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/03/playing-trade-offs-with-maven.html) of him (Stephen is an active maven developer).